# Python and sqlite- checking registration date in table is over a specified time

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, date

I'm struggling on how to create an SQL query using SQLite 3 in Python. I have created a sql table with data added. I think I've set the table data type for registration date to date. When I try to search registrations over a year old I get different errors, dependent on what I search.

The statement I am using is:

```
Cursor = conn.execute("select * from members where MEMBERSHIP_DATE <= DateAdd(1 , GetDate() )")
```

The error I get is:
File "*****", line 99, in searchregistration
    cursor = conn.execute("select * from members where REGISTRATION_DATE <= DateAdd(1 , GetDate() )")
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such function: DateAdd

What is the best way to query my table in order to find registrations older than a year?

The format I have dates in the table is dd/mm/yyyy

Any help or advise is greatly appreciated. This is my first foray into SQLite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax of MySQL [`DATE_ADD()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_add.asp) is :

```
select * from members 
where MEMBERSHIP_DATE <= DATE_ADD(GETDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```

If you are using SQLite like mentioned in the title, then use this:

```
select * from members 
where MEMBERSHIP_DATE <= DATE('now', '+1 day')
```

Comment: Thanks for your speedy response. I've updated the code with your suggestion however I'm getting a syntax error.
cursor = conn.execute("select * from members where REGISTRATION_DATE <= DATE_ADD(GETDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)")
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "10": syntax error

Comment: You are using SQLite and not MySQL. Choose the second code I've provided. @digitalfire